# Why do I have to read a \n in order to keep reading strings?

Tags: c, file, scanf

```
2
1
1
Agatha CHristie
UK
Ultimul Caz Al lui Hercule Poiroit de pe fisier2
```

That is my input file. 
I am reading it using fgets. 
I have written it by myself, there are no blanks at the end of the lines because I hit enter once I was done.

The problem is that I use 2 consecutive fgets to read Agatha CHristie and UK, and after that I have to use an

```
fscanf(input, "\n", trash);
```

in order to read the next line.

Why is that? It's killing me from inside out and it seems to be totally random.

Comment: Post the [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows the problem. You show the input, but please show the code, the expected output, and the actual output as text *in the question*.

Comment: Because every line is terminated by a newline character (and [possible others](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)), and you need to move the read index past it. On the contrary the fact that it is "killing you from inside out" seems to be totally random. If you don't want to do this, you could use `readline`, or just use a single `fscanf` call to read both words *and* the newline.

Comment: Please don't mix input methods like `fgets` and `fscanf`.

Comment: At the end of each line should be only one new line character, since I have created the file this way.  And each of the new line character should be read by the fgets function. Thing which actually happens for the 1st string (Agatha Christie), but doesn't happen for the 2nd one. Why?

Comment: If the next line can't be read, take a look with a text editor or hex dump view of the file to see if there are extra line terminators somehow. Or, create a sample input file with a text editor, to see how it performs.

Comment: @NuSuntStudent please read my first comment. Voting to close.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the number of characters to be read argument of **fgets()** set to the correct size?